# Sorting A Matlab Matrix to a Sequential Series

Tags: matlab, sorting, matrix

I want to order a Nx2 matrix so that the points given would be sorted as though you were playing connect the dots with the values. Meaning if I have in my matrix the value [1 1] and somewhere else in my matrix [1 2] I want to order it in such a way that they would follow one another. And if the next values that would "connect the dots" were to be [1 23] and [2 23] it would continue the sort from there.

For this sort the "connecting dots" are only possible for neighboring points, so [1 1] can only connect to [1 2], [2 1], [2 2], [0 1], [0 0], [1 0], [2 0], or [0 2] (left, right, up, down, and basic diagonals).

Answer (score 0):

Technically you could solve your issue by using the 2-norm. As only up,down,right,left and one diagonal are allowed the 2-norm of the difference of your elements has to be 1 or sqrt(2):

For example:

```
a = [1 2];
b = [2 2];

if(norm(a-b,2) == 1 || norm(a-b,2) == sqrt(2))
    %apply sorting algorithm (quicksort, bubblesort, etc.)
end
```

However you will have to define which element to place where if several answers are possible (e.g. [0 0],[0 1],[1 0],[1 1] or [0 0],[1 1],[1 0],[0 1],etc.)
This will become more problematic the larger N gets.

Maybe you should consider using [an adjacency matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix) as your questions sounds like you are searching for connections between nodes in a graph.

Comment: I agree about the adjacency matrix. Once you have that, you can search only the current vertex's local neighborhood rather than all of the remaining points.